# Displaying 0 results in CodeIgniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I cannot find good documentation that explains what I am looking for.

If I query the database in my Model, and pass the results array to my View, where do I state that if there are 0 results print "There are no results to display?"

Comment: I have read through all the documentation. I understand how to check if an array is empty and loop through results. I am just looking for what is the "best practice" for where to assign such functions.  Do I check the num of results in the model, or wait until they are passed to the view?

Comment: 2 of the 3 answers below recommend handling that in the view. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to display text to the user, that's probably best done in the view.

Assuming you are passing the `result()` array to the view, you can check whether it's empty or not (i.e. has no records):

```
if(empty($query->result())){
    // no records to display
} else {
    // records have been returned
}
```

Otherwise, you can check via the `num_rows()` method if you're dealing with the db object as a whole (and not just `result()`):

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    // records have been returned
} else {
    // no records
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try...

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$a = $query->result_array();

if(count($a) > 0){
  foreach ($a as $row)
  {
    //....
  }
}
```

I recommend you read this link http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: I have read through all the documentation. I understand how to check if an array is empty and loop through results. I am just looking for what is the "best practice" for where to assign such functions. Do I check the num of results in the model, or wait until they are passed to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best done in the view. Assuming you're not using any template engines,

```
<?php if ($result->num_rows() > 0): ?>
  // do something...
<?php else: ?>
  <p>There are no results to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```